# Ember How to retain query parameters while manually refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-easy-form

I am using ember 2.7.0.while manually refreshing the page ember clears the ember-data as well us query parameters, so i am unable to load the page in setupController while refreshing. Is there any possible way to retain both model & query parameters, at least retaining query parameter would be fine to reload my page.

**route.js**

```
model(params) {   
  return this.store.peekRecord("book",params.book_id);
},

setupController(controller,model,params){
  if(!model){
    //fetch book record again if the model is null
  }
  controller.set('isdn',params.queryParams.isdn);
  controller.set('book',model);
}
```

Any help should be appreciable.

**Edited setupController as per Adam Cooper comment :**

```
setupController(controller,model,params){
var isdn = params.queryParams.msisdn;
controller.set('isdn',isdn);
if(!model){
  this.store.findRecord('book', isdn).then((customer) => {
  this.set('book',customer);
},(resp,status) => {
  this.set('errorMessage', `Book with this ${isdn} does not exist.`);
  this.set('book', []);
});
}else{
  controller.set('device',model);
}
}
```

Page gets rendered before "findRecord" returning promise.Is there any way to stop page rendering till find record resolves the promise?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem You could use localStorage? LocalForage may be more suitable for your needs as it adds flexibility and is able to store different datatypes.

Comment: Is there any other option available apart from localStorage?Do we have any listener for refresh event in ember?

Comment: Sorry @velNaga, I'm not an Ember user.

Comment: @DanielShillcock thank you for your quick response.Local storage is my last option. Definitely ember should have some alternative approach so retain query parameters.

Comment: @VelNaga You are right, dont use localStorage. Ember is awesome once u get to know it completely. I use ember extensively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting in route properties instead of controller..

```
setupController(controller, model, params){
var isdn = params.queryParams.msisdn;
controller.set('isdn', isdn);
if(!model){
    this.store.findRecord('book', isdn).then((customer) => {
    controller.set('book', customer);
}, (resp, status) => {
    controller.set('errorMessage', `Book with this ${isdn} does not exist.`);
    controller.set('book', []);
});
}else{
    controller.set('device', model);
}
```

}

Only the controller properties will decorate template.

You can even try the below, why don't you give opportunity to model hook to resolve since that will wait for the Promises to resolve.

```
model(params) {   
    var result = this.store.peekRecord("book",params.book_id);
    if(result !== null){
       result= this.store.findRecord('book', params.book_id)
    }
  return result;
}
setupController(controller,model){    
    controller.set('book',model);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer it is woking like a charm.now I'm able to render the page with model data while page refreshing

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate an actual controller for your route and then define a [queryParams](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_queryParams) property in the controller. It looks like the query param you're trying to hold onto is isdn so your controller should look something like:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['isdn']
});
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response.I am able to retain the queryParams is there any way to retain the ember-data while refreshing?

Comment: i edited my question.Page gets rendering before find record resolves the promise could you please guide me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

"manually refreshing the page ember clears the ember-data as well us query parameters"

Once you completely refresh the browser, a new ember app instance is created and hence ember-data cannot be retained. Ember-data is just for the app on the UI, once ember is exited it will not be retained.

"as well us query parameters"

your query params are part of your url and it should not get cleared. Make sure the below two are present

Include queryParams in ur controller i.e.

```
queryParams: ['param1', 'param2']
```

And in your route make sure you have done

```
queryParams : {
    param1: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    param2: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
}
```

"Page gets rendered before "findRecord" returning promise"

You are not doing something right, is the adapter, model, serializer etc defined correctly(if required) in order to use findRecord? Just to debug return a plain object and make sure ur setupController is called before rendering. i.e.

```
model() {
  return {dummy: 'dummy'};
}
```

Comment: I followed Adam coopers answer and I'm able to retain the query parameter but your answer is little bit different.what is the difference ? Why should I want to queryParams in route ? Which is good practice?Then I hope my adapters are configured correctly it is hitting the database and returning data but it is talking some time also i tried in model function,but no use still control not waiting for promise to resolve. After page rendered control comes to promise resolve but the page is not re rendered

Comment: "Why should I want to queryParams in route", having it in route means setting any of the queryparams would reload the route, i also have found many edge cases where setting in route helps other issues. When you said "After page rendered control comes to promise resolve but the page is not re rendered" were you reffering to the promise in setup-controller? The promise in setup-controller wil never wait. Only beforeModel and after model hooks wait for promise to resolve